# Partial Specialization of class with two integer parameters

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

So I have a class that looks like this:

```
template <unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N = 128>
  class AESLocker {
  public:

    //Default Constructor
    AESLocker() : ENCRYPTION_KEY_LENGTH(N) {
      //Blah blah
    }

    //Contructor
    AESLocker(std::string key, std::string ivec);
```

And I am trying to implement different functions based on the MODE which are mentioned in an file with #defines.

However, I am failing at making two different constructors for 2 modes. Ie I want to partially specialize the constructor.

```
  //constructor
  template<unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
  AESLocker<MODE, N>::AESLocker(std::string key, std::string ivec)  {
    //blah
  }
```

The above template is currently used for all modes and all N. What I want is to specialize for MODE but not N. Ie I want a constructor for all N for mode 1 and another constructor for all N for mode 2.

I've spend the past 30 minutes trying various things.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are special functions, but they are functions nonetheless. The language does not allow partial specialization of template functions, and thus you cannot partially specialize a constructor.

If the changes between the different versions happen in the body (rather than the initialization list), then you can move that logic to a different private function and call it using some other mechanism. Tag dispatch comes to mind:

```
  // Make these private
  template <unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
  void AESLocker<MODE, N>::init(std::string key, std::string ivec, Int2Type<1>) {
      // Specialization for MODE == 1
  }
  template <unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
  template <int X>
  void AESLocker<MODE, N>::init(std::string key, std::string ivec, Int2Type<X>) {
      // Generic for all other modes
  }
  // Dispatch based on MODE
  template<unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
  AESLocker<MODE, N>::AESLocker(std::string key, std::string ivec)  {
    init(std::move(key), std::move(N), Int2Type<MODE>());
  }
```

Note that I used the generic `Int2Type`, forcing the use of a templated `init` for the general case, but if you only want to distinguish `1` from the rest, you could use a tag type with just two options, `0` and `1` and dispatch with:

```
Int2Type<MODE == 1>()
```

In this case both overloads of `init` would be non-templated. Note that there is no practical difference other than the syntax overhead, since functions are generated on demand, which means that only one `init` will be generated per specialization of `AESLocker`.

---

As Jarod42 mentions, in C++11 and above you can also use forwarding constructors to do the same:

```
// private constructors
template <unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
AESLocker<MODE, N>::AESLocker(std::string & key, std::string & ivec, Int2Type<0>) 
: // initializer list
{ // constructor body
}
// public constructor
template <unsigned short MODE, unsigned int N>
AESLocker<MODE, N>::AESLocker(std::string key, std::string ivec)
: AESLocker(std::move(key), std::move(ivec), IntToType<MODE>())
{}
```

Where I have omitted one of the overloads. As an orthogonal change, I have modified the argument types to be referneces to strings (no need to keep moving the `key` and `ivec` objects around, we know the caller and we can do with the strings as we please).

Comment: I can't find `Int2Type` anywhere, where is it from?

Comment: You can define it yourself, there are multiple definitions available in google, but it is simple enough to type yourself: `template <int N> struct Int2Type {};`

Comment: With forward constructor, you don't need `init` (and that also works for initialization list).

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, I was thinking about that... it solves the problem of the initializer list. It is just that I still code C++03 and tend to forget parts of the language I don't use... thanks for pointing this out.